# Last value in a series which meets a condition

Tags: kql

Is it possible to extract the last value in a series, which met a certain condition?
Preferably without using mv-expand.

For example : series [0, 10, 15, 2], condition : element > 10
expected value will be 15

Comment: How about mv-apply?

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable(elements:dynamic)[ dynamic([0, 10, 15, 2])]
|   mv-apply with_itemindex=i element = elements to typeof(int) on 
    (
        where element > 10 
        |   summarize arg_max(i, element)
    )
```

| elements | i | element |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [0,10,15,2] | 2 | 15 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA0VN2wqCQBB9F/yH87gLBhX0EtiPiMiWUw44q7hTavTxKWrNMJwDcy6l02mvNRmqSchrOJejd8I3m2FlJtsnOMx3SnDMbR5HHwDy2rm2rUf0rFXBSsK%20pCFlrFFINxagDXRsqbkb9mrReMTRlAGzwDx9RR39vJepEf/nXBieIq7jN8F1j0LcYDjZ9HaR2i%20e81Tx0AAAAA==)

Comment: :-) .....................